# A better way to float text on top of an image with varying container widths

Tags: html, css, image

I'm redesigning a site and the different sections (header, banner image, main, etc.) have a background that stretches all the way across, however the content is contained to a certain width and that box is centered.

However, in the design the "banner image" (which is a image below the header but above the main content) will extend beyond the width of the rest of the content.  At first this was easy until a need arose to have text on top of the banner image, and that text would need to line up with the rest of the text.

I cannot use CSS background image because on some pages the banner image area will be a slider, which requires  tags.

I have a working solution, but it seems clunky and I was hoping to find a better method: http://jsfiddle.net/PkStg/10/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        header text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="banner">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="banner-text-outer">
            <div class="banner-text-inner">
                <h2>banner text header</h2>
                <p>banner text paragraph</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner-image-wrapper">
        <img src="http://www.brokenbowlakeguide.com/rainbow-trout-1.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        main content text
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header, .banner, .main-content { width: 100%; }
.header { background: red;}
.banner { background: green; }
.main-content { background: yellow; }
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.banner-text-outer {
    position: relative;
}
.banner-text-inner {  
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}

.banner-image-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 300px;
    font-size: 0;
}
.banner-image-wrapper img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Shortening your question will fetch you some answers

Comment: I assume the second `.banner-text-outer` should be `.banner-text-inner`?

Comment: I don't see the use for `.banner-text-outer` ánd `.banner-text-inner`. You can remove `.banner-text-outer` and use padding to align text within (or margin on `h2` and `p` tags). Other then that I think the code looks clean.

Comment: @PaulvdDool It is important if he wants to absolutely position the elements but keep them in flow with the document as well as getting a "layering" effect with `z-index`.

Comment: As designed, your layout assumes that the background image is controlling the height of the `.banner` block element.  If you were to add more text in `.banner-text-inner`, you would run into problems such as: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/PkStg/9/ To get the overlap effect, one of your banner child elements needs to be absolutely positioned, but it has to be the shorter of the two, and you may not know which that will be.  Can you give a min-height to the banner?

Comment: @PaulvdDool I too feel like the .banner-text-outer and .banner-text-inner are what's making it cluttered.  However, I don't think padding/margin isn't an option for when the screen size shrinks the image down to the min-width, causing the text to move as well, rather than stay aligned with the rest of the page's text.

Comment: @MarcAudet Essentially I will have a min-height because all of the images will be the same size.  Is that a safe assumption or would setting the min-height explicitly do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you wanted to not use background-image, but here is a solution which uses that for anyone else who sees the page.

Perhaps your slider could make use of the background-image?

This should do it:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkStg/6/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            header text
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="banner-text-outer">
                <div class="banner-text-inner">
                    <h2>banner text header</h2>
                    <p>banner text paragraph</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            main content text
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.header, .banner, .main-content { width: 100%; }

.header { background: red;}
.banner { background: green; }
.main-content { background: yellow; }
.content-wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.banner {
    background: green url("http://www.brokenbowlakeguide.com/rainbow-trout-1.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it's not COMPLETELY off the table, I just searched far and wide and put a good amount of customization into the slider we are currently using.  Still gave you an upvote for a detailed and workable solution and may revisit the idea.  In your code though, since there's no longer an <img> tag, shouldn't banner-text-outer and banner-text-inner be unnecessary in your solution?

Comment: I assumed you were using them for other styles.

Comment: It's a late acceptance of your answer, but eventually I did break down and use background image replacement =)